# Reading in zip file as a resource causes odd encoding changes

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea, character-encoding, zip

I have a (very large) collection of JSONs that must be distributed as part of a JAR file as a resource. Due to this large number, it is not feasible to programmatically hard-code all their names, as such I have stored them all within a zip file, where I can easily iterate through them.

The relevant code is below:

```
 ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(SchemaReader.class.getResourceAsStream("/org/hl7/fhir/schema/dstu3.zip"));
    ZipEntry entry;
    try {
        while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            String name = entry.getName();
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("fhir.schema.json") || name.equalsIgnoreCase("ResourceList.schema.json")) {
                continue; // Skip over the root definition to prevent duplicates
            }
            String definition = IOUtils.toString(zis);
            zis.closeEntry();
            JsonObject root = new JsonParser().parse(definition).getAsJsonObject();
            JsonObject definitionMap = root.getAsJsonObject("definitions");
            for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> e : definitionMap.entrySet()) {
                definitions.put(name + "#/definitions/" + e.getKey(), root);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Now... this code works fine, when I am running the application w/in my IDE (i.e. whatever IntelliJ does to handle your src/main/resources directory indicated in the POM) but as soon as I attempt to run this same code as part of a packaged JAR, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 5 path $
```

This pertains to the line

```
JsonObject root = new JsonParser().parse(definition).getAsJsonObject();
```

I investigated further with IntelliJ's debugger on running the .jar and discovered that for some reason the extracted JSONs had odd characters encoded in front:

```
ï»¿{"$schema": ...
```

The rest of the JSON appears OK, although I have not exhaustively checked this

This lead me to suspect an encoding error, so I changed the IOUtils#toString call to add various possible encodings.

Unfortunately, I have had no success thus far, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicion is that you are getting a [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Try using the Apache Commons IO [BOMInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html) to wrap the InputStream. Note that the "basic" constructor only drops `ByteOrderMark.UTF_8` BOM's, which is fine in most cases. But if not, try using the constructor that lets you specify other BOMS and add them all (or experiment until you find the right one)

Comment: Can confirm this was the issue, thanks!
Out of interest, why does this only become an issue once the zip is put inside a JAR file?

Comment: @AndrewW It was likely the tool that created the JAR file that added the BOM. I had a case a while back where when loading a couple dozen resources, only one had a BOM that caused a parsing issue. Looking at the git history, a developer different than the one who originally created the resources add the problematic one. They had used a different text editor than the first developer had used. Often times now, I just use the `BomInputStream` as a "just in case" safety to prevent issues when loading resources.